# How can I use Knockout.Combobox together with KnockOut Validation?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm trying to use Knockout.Combobox with Knockout Validation library.

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Combobox

http://jsfiddle.net/Zc9Aj/

```
this.errors = ko.validation.group(this);
this.errors.showAllMessages();
```

The above doesn't work, I assume that the Validation library does not understand how to validate the Combobox binding but how do you link these two libs together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout Validation only supports the Value binding out of box, you can do something like this to get it to support the combobox

http://jsfiddle.net/AWHhr/78/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.comboboxValue = { 
    init: ko.bindingHandlers.validationCore.init
};
```